# AdSense JS Code Leaking Out, Ad Space not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, adsense

I'm trying to put an AdSense Responsive Banner Above and Beneath the posts at: [Here](http://eoto.tech/mi-6-gfxbench)

The Ad Space is not working, while JS code "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" is leaking out.

The site is running on WordPress, and as you can see, Ad Banners work fine when applied through the Widgets. Please help me out here!
I have switch off CloudFlare Rocket Loader as well.

Comment: You should probably describe what you mean by "leaking out".

Comment: Joshua, if you look at the link I have added, you'll see the the code snippet making it's way into the frontend. Now, I'm just a beginner, so I don't know how you describe that. Please help out! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered, it seems to be that you've not added the JavaScript code correctly. You need to add it in using script tags so it's correctly parsed as JavaScript code within the page. Adding this into your HTML/PHP files, *preferably at the bottom **before the closing body tag*** should work.

```js
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

A bit more information [about `script` tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp).